# Solving classical parabolic equation by using Littlewood-Paley theory

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde

Consider the following classical PDE in $R^n$:
$$
\partial_tu(t,x)+\Delta u(t,x)+b(t,x)\cdot\nabla u(t,x)=f(t,x),\quad u(0,x)=0.
$$
Is there any references on solving the above equation by using the Littlewood-Paley theory? More precisely, I wonder whether the following result is known or not:
$$
f\in L^p(R_+\times R^n),\quad b\in L^\infty(R_+;B^\alpha_{q,\infty}(R^n))
$$
with $p>1$ and some conditions on $\alpha,q$ (especially for $\alpha<0$), then there exists a unique solution $u$ to the above equation.

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You may find Chapter 3, in particular section 3.4, of the book *Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations* by H. Bahouri, J.Y. Chemin, and R. Danchin helpful.